# Problems to find a shortest path between pairs origin and destination (Netlogo)

Tags: netlogo, shortest-path

My research is about find a shortest path between an origin and a destination predefined. Both (origin and destination) were located using the GIS extension, because they were obtained by a shape file. I used the command `ask patches gis:intersecting shapefile` to create a person in an origin and a school in the destination.

I have 10 origins and for each I have a specify destination. I noticed that when I use the Dijsktra's algorithm to find the shortest path, for certain origin the destination isn't the respective point but the closest destination.
So, my doubt is: Is the Dijsktra's the best algorithm for my problem or I need to use the A* algorithm?

If the Dijsktra's algorithm is the best, how do I inform the pairs origin and destination in the code?

If the A* algorithm is the best, how do I construct the code in the version 5.0 of Netlogo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about netlogo, but since your question doesn't quote it in the tags I'll assume an algorithm oriented answer is ok.

Dijkstra and A* are similar; both look and find the shortest path from one point to another. A* is more effective when you've got a known-in-advance destination as it optimally looks for the shortest possible path through the heuristics, while dijkstra exapnds more nodes in your graph by searching all directions.

If you find that Dijkstra returns a path to a different destination than the one you expect, you should consider verifying the destination detection: you should conclude the dijkstra searcg when you find THAT destination, not ANY destination.

A* doesn't suffer so much of the same since the heuristics will point them towards the correct destination, but can in special cases find the same problem (i.e. shortest path to correct destination passes through a different destination).

TO be more precise, I'd need some code - pseudocode is ok - of your conclusion, or details on the graph.

Comment: Sorry for quoting Netlogo in the Tags. I´m beginner in this site.
Thanks for your answers. 
My code is in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/94n47k11089uno5/Code.docx

For example, to the agent “people” with xcor=-1 and ycor=19 (“people” in the highest point in the map) the correct destination (destiny) is the acesso 324, but the algorithm gives me acesso 356.
 
Note: In the map, acesso 324 is located before that acesso 356.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with NetLogo; I'm also not familiar with the language you used for variables and comments... so I'm hard put to understand your code.
Can you point me to where you set the destination for the algorithm, and to where you verify if the target has been reached?

Comment: There's nothing called acessoXXX in the map that I can see; it would seem you iterate through all the "people" to find their route; might want to try with just one to verify the algorithm first - with increasing number of destinations. 
The fact the destination is "above" is irrelevant, the preference goes to the first node expanded by the Dijkstra algorithm that satisfies the completion strategy.

Comment: For example, in the figure (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggmqqej66l9jec8/Duvida2_SOF.jpg) you can see a “people” in a red circle and other point with the same circle (red). In this case and in according with algorithm, the “people” and the other red circle are the origin and the destination, respectively. But in this case, the correct destination is the circle green. In other words, the algorithm chose the destinations closely (red circle)….

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the point I'm making - the point of the algorithm you need to address is "how the destination is identified". Which is the most likely culprit.

Comment: Ok, I understood Calimar. But I still don’t know how to do this…….i´m trying…..Thanks for all.